# c# Signing XML Document: What is in the x509 certificate

Tags: c#, x509certificate, verification, signing

I'm incorporating a software license system into a program of mine.
The client asks for a license, sends me the data I need, then I generate an XML file, being the license file that my program must check at the clients side.

So I generate a x509 certificate on my development computer (win10) and sign the license file.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = store.Certificates;
X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
X509Certificate2Collection signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectDistinguishedName, $"CN={CertificateName}", false);

X509Certificate2 cert = signingCert[0]; // has private and public
store.Close();        

CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription), "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
var exportedKeyMaterial = signingCert[0].PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true);

var key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24));
key.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
key.FromXmlString(exportedKeyMaterial);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
// LicenseInfo is the info about her computer etc. my client provides, eg. by e-mail
using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(LicenseInfo))
{
    doc.Load(sr);
}

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
signedXml.SigningKey = key;
signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

Reference reference = new Reference();
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
reference.Uri = "";
reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
signedXml.AddReference(reference);

KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));
signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
signedXml.ComputeSignature();

XmlElement sig = signedXml.GetXml();

doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(sig,true));
if (doc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
{
    doc.RemoveChild(doc.FirstChild);
}
// and here it finally is: the license!
LicenseText = doc.OuterXml;
```

The signature goes into the license file which will then look like this, after signing:

```
<License>
  <MailAddress>....</MailAddress>
  <LicenseNr>8309847560354</LicenseNr>
  <RequestTimeStamp>8/15/2019 11:28:47 AM</RequestTimeStamp>
  <ExpirationTimeStamp>8/14/2020 11:28:47 AM</ExpirationTimeStamp>
  <X5>78-BB-2F-65-4blabla45-A8-B5-4D-82</X5>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
<Reference URI="">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
<DigestValue>Gg9WLq12JSYFh6tatRTCnGbzEzMg8PidcXK4iWwPcXg=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>JdC09BIeHcw8...q24JFVseBZWXOo==</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<X509Data>
<X509Certificate>MIIC8zCCAd+gAwIBAgIQgwuqv2X..........oP7f5f</X509Certificate>
</X509Data>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</License>
```

What is in that <X509Certificate/> ?
My public key?
If so, I do not need to include my public key in the program as an embeded resource because it will be in my clients license file, that must be processed anyway...
Correct?
The   will not include my private key, I hope...?

Here is how i (try to) verify the license validity (not including the expiration date, only seeing if the license file was not tampered with)

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();

xmlDocument.Load(Name); // the license file

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDocument);

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Signature");
signedXml.LoadXml((XmlElement)nodeList[0]);

RSACryptoServiceProvider Key = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(new CspParameters(24));

Key.ToXmlString(false);

return signedXml.CheckSignature(Resources.PubKey.FromXmlString()); // ????? or what?
```

So:

1: What is in the X509Certificate in the signature?

2: Verification does not work. Any suggestions?

3: Do I include my public key in the program that checks the license, or is the signature itself the source?

PS:

Please, don't point out that this will not give me 100% security. I know.
My questions are about X509, not about guarding against theft. That is another, much broader, issue. It's interesting, programming this stuff and learning.

Comment: If the program trusted the contents of the license file to know what public key to trust, do you not see the problem there? What if someone else generates a key and signs a license file. Should your program trust that input? Also, be aware that this'll slow down amateurs but not anyone determined to remove this check (who can just substitute their own keys into the program or compile out the check altogether) whilst introducing unfamiliar complexity for *you* and your legitimate customers.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the content of the license file?
I know this is not enough: I need to hide the checking point well.
I I know i will never get 100%

Comment: This is how I see it. The client needs to have the public server certificate when receiving the license file. That way the client is able to verify the validity of the license file by using the public key of the server certificate. Off course the certificate on the client end should not contain the private key. When your licens server generates the signature it should be done with the private key of the certificate. Since the certificate on the license server is controlled by you. You should not have any problem with storing the private key for the certificate.

Comment: When I make a certificate with makecert, I get a public *and* a private key. Also in the Win10 store, they go together. That's why I thought a certificate is always a combination of the two. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Structure_of_a_certificate says that is not so: a certificate does *not necessarily* contain a private one. I cite: " Unfortunately, some of these extensions are also used for other data such as private keys." So I'd say my confusion is not entirely surprising.

Comment: I guess when you run makecert you will most likely get a *.cer file and a *.pvk file. The *.cer file is your public certificate containing the public key of the key pair. The *.cer file should be the one you install on the client. You can create a private certificate packet with 'pvk2pfx.exe' which will bundle cer and pvk file in one. output of this is a *.pfx file which imports nicely into the server certificate and private key store. pfx file should be the one you install on the licens server. If you choose to you can protect your private key with a password.

Comment: @Thomas K: for your information: MakeCert can make a certificate in the Win10 stores. No extra files to worry about. C# will neatly get the certificates from the store. No problem there.
But then: see my 3 questions.

Comment: You should include the public key in the program that checks the licens, or else you can not decrypt the signature to verify the licens genuineness. How you then choose to embed the public key is up to you.
I would properbly get it directly from the certificate on the client machine, but I suppose you could as well have it hardcoded in the licences checking code.